# sending data after an accept()

Tags: c, sockets

i have written a small server that accept connections in c.it simply accepts a connection and is supposed to send data when the connection is accepted.but it doesn't!
it accepts the connection but never sends any data(lines after the accept() call never execute).

```
//Server!
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32.lib")
using namespace::std;
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int sockd,newsockd,status=0;
    WSADATA ws;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2),&ws);
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    cout<<getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", "6164", &hints, &res)<<endl;
    sockd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    cout<<"SOCKET NUMBER="<<sockd<<endl;
    cout << "BIND STATUS=" << bind(sockd,res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen)<<endl;
    status = listen(sockd, 16);
    if (status >= 0){
        cout << "Now Listening On Port 6164 TCP!"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        return WSAGetLastError();
    }
    struct sockaddr_storage theirs;
    newsockd=accept(sockd, (struct sockaddr*)&theirs,(socklen_t*) sizeof(theirs));
    send(newsockd, "Hello!", 18, 0);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most readable code since a long time....

Comment: @ckruczek so the problem is...?

Comment: You better read how to format your code better in your question so you might get repu for asking a question. Although its much easier to read your question and to get the main point of your code.

Comment: @ckruczek can i get some help now?.btw i need help not repu

Comment: show us all your code, from the creation of the socket to the close call and check for return values, especially of send. maybe the remote socket is already closed when you try to send stuff

Comment: No you don't get help from me. Stackoverflow lifes from well formed questions. Yours is not.

Comment: You should be checking the return values of `accept` and `send`.

Comment: @dbush thanks.accept fails for some reason and returns -1. but why? i have checked my listen() call status and it returns zero

Comment: WSAGetLastError() may be usefull

Comment: '(socklen_t*) sizeof(theirs)' - no, bad cast.  Load the length into a var, eg 'socklen_t sLen=sizeof(theirs);' and pass '&sLen'.

Comment: @robin.koch ty so much 10014 error  code. better google it

Comment: It's 'WSAEFAULT; 10014. Bad address'.   Fix the bad cast on .socklen_t*

Comment: @MartinJames finally!. thank you! should be cast to (int*)

Comment: ^^whatever:)  The point is that the length is an in/out parameter and must be an lvalue.

Comment: @ckruczek yeah.  It is a shock to see code with no single-letter 'i,j,k,' var names:(

Comment: Lesson learned: Do not wildly cast around to just make warnings or errors go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'(socklen_t*) sizeof(theirs)' - no, bad cast. sizeof(theirs) is, like 20-ish, and dereferencing address 20-ish is illegal on most systems.

Try:

```
socklen_t sLen=sizeof(theirs);
..
newsockd=accept(sockd, (struct sockaddr*)&theirs,&sLen);
```

Note:  you may need sLen after the call to, say, shove a null in at the end of the returned peer address, (not sure if one gets put in by the accept call).

Answer (score 0):

You never assign `newsockd` to the result of `accept`.

`accept` returns a new file descriptor related to the client socket.

Change your code to :

```
newsockd = accept(sockd, (struct sockaddr*)&theirs,(socklen_t*) sizeof(theirs));
```

Comment: sorry forgot to paste the correct code.
the program compiles fine.

Comment: "*Change your code to :*" no, as this "*`(socklen_t*) sizeof(theirs))`*" is a killer.